# How to "map" with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
import * as React from 'react';

//emulating a random robot image from the site
//also components also return one element, and one element only!!
//see below, Card is just returning one big div element, thats it
//in img src, we are doing each individual element as id to randomize the robot images

//in parameters, it is destructuring

interface CardProps {
  name: string
  email: string
  id?: number 
}

export const Card = ({name, email, id}: CardProps) => {
    <div className='tc grow bg-light-green br3 pa3 ma2 dib bw2 shadow-5'>
    <img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=200x200`} />
    <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <p>{email}</p>
      </div>
</div>
}


// const Card = ({ name, email, id }) => {
//   return (
//     <div className='tc grow bg-light-green br3 pa3 ma2 dib bw2 shadow-5'>
//       <img alt='robots' src={`https://robohash.org/${id}?size=200x200`} />
//       <div>
//         <h2>{name}</h2>
//         <p>{email}</p>
//       </div>
//     </div>
//   );
// }

export default Card;
```

CARD COMPONENT

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';
import { string, number } from 'prop-types';

//we are destructuring robots into parameter because we need to grab robot info
//we are grabbing robot info already from ./Card

//in CardComponent, we are iterating thru each robot user and info
interface CardListProps = {
    robots: Object
    user: number
    i: number
    key: number
    id: number
    name: string
    email: string
}



const CardList = ({robots}) => {
    return (
    <div>
        {
    robots.map((user, i) =>{
        return( 
        <Card
            key={i} 
            id={robots[i].id} 
            name={robots[i].name} 
            email={robots[i].email} 
            /> 
        ); 
        })
}
    </div>
    );
}

export default CardList;
```

I am working on a project to be entirely done in TypeScript. I'm still very new to TS so I'm going back to an old React project and switching the entire codebase to TS for practice. Then I hit one roadblock.. How do I "map" this component here in TypeScript?

All I want to do is iterate through key, id, name, and email of Card. Thanks :)

Comment: The same way you do in Javascript? What error (if any) is it giving you? And why `robots[i].property` when you've already named it `user`? Why are you typing `robots` as `Object` if it's an Array?

Comment: So you want `({robots}: {robots: CardListProps[]}) => ... ` maybe?  It would be nice if your code above constituted a [mcve] as described in "[ask]", so someone could test before posting an answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm getting a 'JSX element type void is not a constructor function for JSX elements' when I changed the filetype from .js to .tsx . Hmm, there must be another way to map through the props in TS since I'm getting a lot of squiggly lines from this.

Comment: The way you map a function to an array is absolutely fine, it's just the type declarations that are messing up with you. I think one more thing that is missing in your question is the Card component. Could you please post it as well?

Comment: @rishat Ok I listed the Card Component. Feel free to correct me on any code that could be implemented together or correctly. Okay so if I correct the type declarations, no more squiggly lines? Cool, thanks!

Comment: I think it's a syntactic typo in the Card component: currently it returns nothing (the commented out version below looks correct though). Instead of curly braces that wrap the whole body of the function after the arrow, can you please try round brackets? Like, instead of `(x) => {y}`, try `(x) => (y)`.